# SAS problem: sum up rows and divide till it reach a specific value

Tags: sas

I have the following problem, I would like to sum up a column and divide the sum every line through the sum of the whole column till a specific value is reached. so in Pseudocode it would look like that:

```html
data;
set auto;
sum_of_whole_column = sum(price);
subtotal[i] = 0;
i =1;
do until (subtotal[i] = 70000)
subtotal[i] = (subtotal[i] + subtotal[i+1])/sum_of_whole_column
i = i+1
end;
run;
```

I get the error that I haven't defined an array... so can I use something else instead of subtotal[i]?and how can I put a column in an array? I tried but it doesn't work (data = auto and price the column I want to put into an array)

```html
data invent_array;
set auto;
array price_array {1} price;
run;
```

EDIT: maybe the dataset I used is helpful :)

```html
DATA auto ;
  LENGTH make $ 20 ;
  INPUT make $ 1-17 price mpg rep78 ;
CARDS;
AMC Concord        4099 22 3 
AMC Pacer          4749 17 3 
Audi 5000          9690 17 5 
Audi Fox           6295 23 3 
BMW 320i           9735 25 4 
Buick Century      4816 20 3 
Buick Electra      7827 15 4 
Buick LeSabre      5788 18 3 
Cad. Eldorado     14500 14 2 
Olds Starfire      4195 24 1 
Olds Toronado     10371 16 3 
Plym. Volare       4060 18 2 
Pont. Catalina     5798 18 4 
Pont. Firebird     4934 18 1 
Pont. Grand Prix   5222 19 3 
Pont. Le Mans      4723 19 3 
;
RUN;
```

Comment: What would an ARRAY have to do with this?  What is the set of variables you want to reference by using an array?

Comment: SAS `data step` processes data line by line so it doesn't need a loop, there is always a loop. You can look backwards easily in the loop, it's much harder to look forward as SAS literally hasn't read that data yet. It reads one line at a time. To hold values across these rows `RETAIN` is used, implicit retain occurs within the 1SUM1 statement (not function).

Comment: And showing input is helpful, but without the expected output it's only a piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing your point but your subtotal will never be equal to 70 000 if you divide by the sum of its column. The maximum value will be 1. Your incremental sum however can be equal or superior to 70 000.

```
data stage1;
retain _sum 0;
set auto;
_sum = sum(_sum, price);
if _sum < 70000 then output;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.*, t1._sum/sum(price) as subtotal
from stage1 as t1;
quit;
```

```
   subtotal
 0.0607268256
 0.1310834235
 0.2746411058
 0.3679017467
 0.5121261056
 0.5834753107
 0.6994325842
 0.7851820027
       1
```